# Receive background notification for incoming phone call?

Tags: ios, phone-call

We have an Android app which has the following broadcast receiver in the manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".IncomingCallReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

It fires whenever a call is being made or received whether the app is active or not (eg. after cold boot).

What we want to accomplish is the same effect for an iOS app written in Swift: to be able to receive a notification for an incoming call even if the app is not running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry to say but this is not possible in iOS.

In iOS it is not allowed and possible to receive phone call event to handle that. No app can access the native phone app, and call logs at all. Other than that to access contacts user has to approve this.